# Android Google Maps navigation inside my application - possible?

Tags: android, web-services, google-maps

I wondering is it possible to draw a route from the Google Maps API inside my own application.

For example, this solution:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr="+ latitude + "," + longitude + "&daddr=" + latitude + "," + longitude));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps","com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Will start a Google Maps application and start navigation in that application. Is it possible to the the same but to draw that route inside my `MapFragment` Object, or `GoogleMap` Object?

I read the official documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

And it nowhere mention that navigation is possible inside `MapFragment`, but also doesn't mention that it isn't possible..

Comment: Yes, it's possible using Xml or Json of the google maps:
[same problem solved][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24993046/2073039